# Angular grid reverse columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid, angular-grid

We are using `angular-grid` to display a grid of dynamic columns. ie:

```
col1    col2   col3    col4   col5    col6   col7    col8   col9    colx
```

The columns are being returned in the correct order, however, angular grid is displaying them back to front.

```
colx    col9   col8    col7   col6    col5   col4    col3   col2    col1
```

Is there a way to reverse these columns. We cant use column destinations, as we have no idea how many columns will be returned.

Comment: Are you using ng-grid? Can you create and link to a Plunk that demonstrates this?

Answer (score 1):

You should list them in the `columnDefs` in the correct order.

The related documentation:
http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/

If you don't know the columns before getting them, you can set this property after you received the data, based on for example the first row.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define the `columnDefs` for your data set. You can do this with your dynamic columns by doing something like this:

```
$scope.myData = [
  {name: 'col1', value: 'abc'},
  {name: 'col2', value: 'def'},
  // etc.
  {name: 'colx', value: 'xyz'}
];

$scope.$watchCollection('myData', function (new_myData, old_myData) {
  angular.forEach(new_myData, function(item, index) {
    $scope.columnDefs[index] = {
      field: item.name,
      value: item.value
    };
  });
});
```